# Facing issues in migrating from ADAL JS to MSAL JS

Tags: angular, authentication, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-msal, azure-adal-deprecation

Hope you all are safe & sound, I was migrating my angular app authentication from ADAL JS to MSAL JS.

In ADAL JS, I have my ADAL Config as follows and the authentication works as expected:

```
adalConfig: {
    tenant: 'GUID',
    clientId: 'GUID',
    redirectUri: window.location.origin
    ......
    ...... // other properties
 }
```

In MSAL Config I tried to set the same properties in app.module.ts

```
MsalModule.forRoot({
      auth: {
          clientId: "GUID", // Same as the client ID of ADAL JS
          authority: https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenant GUID>/, // Same as the tenant GUID of ADAL JS
          redirectUri: OAuthSettings.redirectUri, // This is your redirect URI
      },
      cache: {
        cacheLocation: 'localStorage',
       // storeAuthStateInCookie: true, // set to true for IE 11
    }
```

However I keep on getting this error

> "Please set the correlationId as a valid guid"

I tried looking at this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/msal-js-sso#sso-in-adaljs-to-msaljs-update) from Microsoft, but it mentions nothing about the authority.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

`correlationId` would be seen in MSAL logs. As the [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/msal-logging?tabs=javascript) shows, correlationId is a unique identifier, used to map the request with the response for debugging purposes.

You could try the code from this [link](http://johnliu.net/blog/2018/11/migrate-angular-spa-from-adaljs-to-msal-because-it-is-awesome):

```
MsalModule.forRoot({
    clientID: '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000',
    authority: "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/",
    validateAuthority: true,
    redirectUri: window.location.origin,
    cacheLocation: 'localStorage',
    postLogoutRedirectUri: window.location.origin,
    navigateToLoginRequestUrl: false,
    popUp: false,
    unprotectedResources: ["https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/"],
    protectedResourceMap: protectedResourceMap,
    logger: loggerCallback,
    correlationId: "1000",
    level: LogLevel.Info,
    piiLoggingEnabled: true
})
....
```